# Jenkins pipeline to SSH into an instance and call a function

Tags: jenkins, groovy, ssh, jenkins-pipeline

How to create a function `def test()` which does some steps after `ssh`ing into an instance

I have something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

def test() {
    cd $testPath
    mv test*.txt archiveFiles
    sh "someScript.sh"
}

pipeline { 
agent java
    parameters {
       string(
            name: 'testPath',
            defaultValue: '/home/ubuntu/testFiles',
            description: 'file directory'
        )
    }
        stages {
        stage(test) {
            steps{
                script{
                    sh "ssh ubuntu@IP 'test()'"
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to `ssh` into an instance and do the steps in the function `test()` by calling it
I am getting an error  like this:
`bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
ERROR: script returned exit code 1`

Answer (score 2):

We use the SSH plugin as follows:

```
steps {
    timeout(time: 2, unit: 'MINUTES') {
        sshagent(credentials: ['local-dev-ssh']) {
                    sh "ssh -p 8022 -l app ${ENVIRONMENT_HOST_NAME} './run-apps.sh ${SERVICE_NAME} ${DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG_PREFIX}-${env.BUILD_NUMBER}'"
        }
    }
}
```